# Intercepting value changes rewriting values in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular.js app I'm rendering an input field bound to a scope variable where the user can enter a quantity.

What I'm trying to do now is to intercept all changes to my bound variable and in case a non integer quantity is entered or the field is left blank I'd like to set my scope variable to 1.

I managed to do this via watches but I'm running into errors since my quantity variable gets modified in my watch function too:

```
$scope.$watch('quantity', function (oldValue, newValue) {
    // Some Code ...
    if (!valid) {
        $scope.quantity = 1;
    }
});
```

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Both proposed solutions work. I picked the timeout solution because it's less work around for the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$timeout` to force to do `scope.apply`. Simply, you can do like this

```
$scope.check = function () {
    // Some Code ...
    if (!valid) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.quantity = 1;
        });
    }
};
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GM8pm/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you could use a directive for the numbers only portion or your question, here is one that I wrote and use, I don't know if this would resolve your watch function issues:

```
myApp.directive('numbersOnly', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                // this next if is necessary for when using ng-required on your input.
                // In such cases, when a letter is typed first, this parser will be called
                // again, and the 2nd time, the value will be undefined
                if (inputValue == undefined)
                    return ''
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }

                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I also use an `ngBlur` (pre AngularJS 1.2) directive to limit the callbacks that a watch performs, don't know if that would help in your instance.